# Initial value in django form dropdown is not empty?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form where I define selection criterias for report.
One of the dropdowns 'building'  that is auto populated from the model , should be not mandatory and have default value as empty. I can't achieve the empty part .

I want first field in my dropdown

in my form

```
building = forms.IntegerField(
widget=forms.Select(
    choices=Building.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
    ) , required=False
 )
```

in view file when I initialize the code

```
form = PaymentRangeForm(initial = {'building': 0 })
```

I use crispy forms in my template but I don't think it makes any difference.

```
     <form method="POST"  class="form" action="" method="get">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy}} 
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary">Search</button>
    </form>
```

I am not getting any error but  the default is not empty it has a value of first record from the model.

What I am missing?

Comment: Do you load crispy form in your template ?

Comment: yes I do. I just updated in my original post.

Comment: provide your template please

Comment: I updated the original post with form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Solution was simple. In my from file I have added

```
from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH
```

and updated the form

```
class PaymentRangeForm(forms.Form):

    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'} ))
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'} ))
    building = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + list(Building.objects.values_list('id', 'name')), required=False)
```

Comment: you could more easily do `...forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('','-------')] + list(Building.ob....`.

Answer (score 0):

load crispy_forms_tags top of the template.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

 <form method="POST"  class="form" action="" method="get">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy}} 
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank but No. currently they are already  there in my includes. If they  not there crispy tag in my form  would give an error .

Answer (score -1):

According to [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/), perhaps you could try it out without the .all() as below

choices=Building.objects.values_list('id', 'name')

Comment: No, it makes no difference. Same result in both cases.